# How to deploy a Firestore trigger on all document writes using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, triggers, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I have a Firestore db that is defined like this:

```
/my_requests //collection
/{request-a} //document
/{request-b} //document
/{request-c} //document
```

So essentially a single collection called "my_requests" which contains many documents, each representing an individual request.

I am trying to deploy a cloud function using "gcloud functions deploy" for any 'write' event on any "request" that is inserted or modified. I've tried a number of paths trying to find the magic solution but so far nothing has worked. For example the one I feel should work looks like this:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_firestore_handler 
--runtime python37
--trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write
--trigger-resource projects/my-project-id/databases/(default)/documents/my_requests/{request}
```

So how does one create a path that will fire on a "request" document write event?

Thanks

Comment: I'm unclear.  Are you saying that you want to use a wildcard that matches a substring of the name of the collection, and not the entire name of the collection?

Comment: Well, perhaps I am unclear myself how Firestore is meant to be used. I'm just starting with Firestore so I'll admit I'm a complete noob. If I was to write a user-story for what I want it would say "As a user I want a cloud function to fire every time a new document is added to the 'my-requests' collection. Really thats about it. So what I need an answer to is: how do I write my trigger-resource path to get that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully deployed a Cloud Function via Cloud Shell triggered by a write event.

In order to achieve this i just follow this [Google Cloud Firestore Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#event_types).

My deploy command looks like this:

```
gcloud functions deploy myFunctionName  --runtime python37  
--trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write
--trigger-resource "projects/myProjectName/databases/(default)/documents/users/{username}"
```

You should just add double quotes arround your resource path.

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_firestore_handler 
--runtime python37
--trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write
--trigger-resource "projects/my-project-id/databases/(default)/documents/my_requests/{request}"
```

Comment: That was it! I just needed the double quotes. Thanks for the help!